# Add another XML file to existing XML file using MSXML C++

Tags: c++, xml, visual-c++, msxml, msxml6

I am working on the project, where I am using MSXML parser to create and parse the XML documents. The existing implementation uses CMarkup and it has a function to add another XML document to existing document using `addsubdoc(xmlfile)` but When I am trying that with MSXML parser it is not happening.

Does anybody has a solution regarding it.

for example what I have tried:

```
CString str = L"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n"
            L"<Book>"
            L"<Text>"
            L"<Name>CPP</Name>"
            L"<Author>Henry</Author>"
            L"</Text>"
            L"</Book>";
CString sub = L"<Text>"
              L"<Name>5656</Name>"
              L"<Author>Steve</Author>"
              L"</Text>"
```

The xml I want is:

```
<Book>
<Text>...</Text>
<Text>..New added..</Text>
</Book>
```

Now I want to add the sub to str in a way that it auto add under Book tag. SO I did:

```
pXMLDom1->loadXML(_bstr_t(str));
pXMLDom2->loadXML(_bstr_t(sub));
// To get root node
CString root = (LPCSTR)pXMLDom1->GetfirstChild()->baseName;
pXMLDom1->selectSingleNode(root)->appendChild(pXMLDom2);
```

but it does not adding the data.

EXAMPLE CODE to TEST:

```
#import <msxml6.dll>
#include "msxml2.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <atlstr.h>

void main()
{

MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom1;
MSXML2::IXMLDOMDocumentPtr pXMLDom2;
HRESULT hr = pXMLDom.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
HRESULT hr2 = pXMLDom2.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);

CString str = L"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-16\"?>\r\n"
              L"<Book>"
              L"<Text>"
              L"<Name>CPP</Name>"
              L"<Author>Henry</Author>"
              L"</Text>"
              L"</Book>";

CString sub = L"<Text>"
              L"<Name>5656</Name>"
              L"<Author>Steve</Author>"
              L"</Text>";

pXMLDom1->loadXML(_bstr_t(str));
pXMLDom2->loadXML(_bstr_t(sub));

printf("Dynamically created DOM:\n%s\n", static_cast<PCSTR>(pXMLDom1->xml));
printf("Dynamically created DOM:\n%s\n", static_cast<PCSTR>(pXMLDom2->xml));

// To get root node
CString root = (LPCSTR)pXMLDom1->GetfirstChild()->baseName;
pXMLDom1->selectSingleNode(root)->appendChild(pXMLDom2);

printf("Merged XML:\n%s\n", static_cast<PCSTR>(pXMLDom1->xml));
}
```

Comment: I'd guess `pXMLDom2->loadXML` is failing as `sub` is not valid XML

Comment: @AlanBirtles I created that as example, just corrected the xml to give an idea what I want.. It will be great if you can help, I am stuck! :(

Comment: Have you tried checking the result of `loadXml`? I guess `pXMLDom2->selectSingleNode` should be `pXMLDom1`?

Comment: yes.. loadXML working fine, on printing it is giving the correct output. and yes selectSingleNode is pXMLDom1, I changed it.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles added the example code..

Comment: Is this the actual code you are using? It won't compile due to code being outside of a function, please provide a [mre]

Comment: yes using the same code.. did not added the function,, just added it as main()..

Comment: are you sure this is a [mre]? It doesn't compile for me and `pXMLDom1` and `pXMLDom2` are both null?

Comment: @AlanBirtles yes, the same code working for me.. you can try adding 
HRESULT hr = pXMLDom1.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
HRESULT hr2 = pXMLDom2.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML2::DOMDocument60), NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
sometime it works with that!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pXMLDom1->documentElement->appendChild(pXMLDom2->documentElement)
```

Or, slightly modifying your code:

```
CString root = (LPCSTR)pXMLDom1->documentElement;
pXMLDom1->selectSingleNode(root)->appendChild(pXMLDom2->documentElement);
```

Also, note that `pXMLDom1->GetfirstChild()->baseName` gives you `"xml"`.